# C#, .NET, Entity Framework: pdfViewer.LoadDocument cant stream pdf from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Pdfviewer can't stream PDF file from database. I can't understand to what I missed.

There is `readTimeOut` and `writeTimeOut`.

```
private void repbtnRaporDosyasıGoruntule_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            var report = _userContext.Reports.Find(gridViewRapor.GetFocusedRowCellValue(colID));
            
            frmPdfGoruntuleme frmpdfgoruntuleme = new frmPdfGoruntuleme(report.ReportFile);
            frmpdfgoruntuleme.ShowDialog();
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("başarısız");
        }
}

public partial class frmPdfGoruntuleme : Form
{
    public frmPdfGoruntuleme(byte[] doc)
    {
        //Hata var, incelenecek.
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(doc);

        pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(ms);
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

I'm trying to show pdf from database but I don't understand what is wrong...

Comment: I want to store it in the database and view the file without downloading it. Do you have a solution suggestion for this?

Comment: Problem fixed, this method working now. Just "InitializeComponent();" must be first line on the cons. method. I wasted 3 days for this. I can preview pdf file without download with this method.